# How can insert spaces at the beginning of another line in libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

There are two lines in one paragraph:

[image]

The cursor located at the beginning of the second line,ahead of the word `long_window`,now i want to add 4 spaces ahead of `long_window` as desired below:

[image]

,why can't insert any space when pressing space bar?

I have got an answer in [why-cant-i-add-extra-spaces-in-writer/35426](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/why-cant-i-add-extra-spaces-in-writer/35426)

```
Tools → AutoCorrect → AutoCorrect Options → Options tab: uncheck “Ignore double spaces.”
```

I did as the webpage instructed,it took no effect.

[image]

Comment: Hypothesis: it is a single line that wraps (i.e. there is no newline character between `long_window=` and `long_window,`). When you add spaces, they get added to the end of the upper part. Select `View`, `Nonprinting Characters` and see those spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The indenting arrangement you want is referred to as a "hanging indent".

The following is from https://help.libreoffice.org/7.6/en-US/text/swriter/guide/indenting.html.

> **Hanging indents**
>
> For a hanging indent, enter a positive value for Before text and a
> negative value for First line.
>
> The Hanging Indent icon is found in the Paragraph section of the
> Properties sidebar. Click on this icon to switch the values of Before
> text and First line. This enables you to toggle a paragraph between an
> indented first line and a hanging indent.
>
> To create a hanging indent: Enter a first line indent where you want
> the indent to start, then click the Hanging Indent icon to create the
> hanging indent.
>
> [image: Hanging Indent icon]
>
> The Hanging Indent command can be added as a button to a toolbar, an
> item in a menu or context menu, or a shortcut key.